# List comprehension to append an element to a tuple

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array

```
arr = np.array([
        [1, (10, 20, 30, 40)],
        [2, (10, 20, 30, 40)],
        [5, (11, 22, 33, 44)]
      ])
```

I wonder if there's a way that I can get :

```
ans = [
        [1, 10, 20, 30, 40],
        [2, 10, 20, 30, 40],
        [5, 11, 22, 33, 44]
      ]
```

using list comprehension in python.

I've tried:

```
ans = [list(row[1]).append(row[0]) for row in arr]
```

but got [None, None, None] as the output

Comment: That's not a numpy array, so your question is moot. Please provide code that matches your prose.

Comment: `[[first, *rest] for first, rest in arr]`

Comment: `append` would put `1`, `2`, and `5` at the *end* of the respective lists anyway, not at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` returns `None`, not the list being appended to. (Also, `append` would insert the item at the wrong end anyway.)

```
ans = [[x, *y] for x, y in arr]
```